# how to vb.net date save to mysql date with no 0000-00-00

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datetime, windows, date-conversion

I've been killing brain cell for over 5 hours with this question. 
how to properly save a date from vb.net to mysql date without getting the 0000-00-00all the time.

I have tried multiple suggestions where you format the date value before entering but it gets me the same result ex:

```
Dim departDate As Date
Dim d As String = Format(departDate, "05/05/2007")
```

in which i tested and didnt works i still got the 0000-00-00

I've tried:

```
    Dim changeFormatDate As Date
    Dim AddFechaListadoCasas2 as String
    changeFormatDate = AddCasasListadoDatePicker.Text
    AddFechaListadoCasas2 = changeFormatDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

which still gives me on mysql the 0000-00-00

I also tried this example:

```
Dim myDate as DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(x, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

and trying to save to mysql still gave me the 0000-00-00

in my program im grabbing the date from a datepicker as text then swtich it to a string and try to save it to the database like that. if necessary i would love to convert it to a date with the format yyyy-MM-dd which is necessary for MySQL but everything i've done above it still shows me the 0000-00-00 which is frustrating.

any help would be very appreciated it.

Leo

here is the MySQL insert statement i have on my program.

```
AddFechaListadoCasas2 = AddCasasListadoDatePicker.Text
        AddFechaCierreCasas2 = AddFechaCierreCasas.Text


SqlVentaCasas = "INSERT INTO VentaCasas (ID, Direccion, Ciudad_Municipio, Zona_Localidad, Barrio, " & _
                                    "Estatus, Precio, Unidad, Departamento, Conjunto, Estrato, Matricula_Inmobiliaria, Cedula_Catastral," & _
                                    "Escritura, Notaria, Ano, Area_Metros_2, Tipo_de_Construccion, Niveles, Habitaciones, Garajes," & _
                                    "Techo, Vista, Picina, Cocina_Integral, Bar, Cuarto_Bano_Servicio, Antejardin, Equipos," & _
                                    "Aire_Acondicionado, Detalles_addicionales, Estilo, Ano_Construccion, Orientacion, Banos, Parqueos," & _
                                    "Piso, Balcon, Jacuzzi_Sauna, Chimenea, Hall_Television, Zona_lavanderia, Patio, Accesorios," & _
                                    "Calefaccion, Administracion, Amenidades, Impuestos, Condiciones, Ocupacion," & _
                                    "Cuota_Administracion, Restricciones, Seguridad, Mostrar, Comision, Fecha_Listado, " & _
                                    "Agente_Cooperante, Fecha_Expiracion, CiudadEscritura, Agente, Licensia, Compania, NumeroPersonal," & _
                                    "NumeroCompania, NumeroFax, Email, AreaLotesM2, PrecioOriginal, Account_Creator, NumeroDias ) VALUES ('" & _
                                    AddIDCasas2 & "','" & _
                                    AddDireccionCasas2 & "','" & AddCiudadCasas2 & "','" & AddZonaCasas2 & "','" & AddBarrioCasas2 & "','" & _
                                    AddEstatusCasas2 & "'," & AddPrecioCasas2 & ",'" & AddUnidadCasas2 & "','" & AddDepartamentoCasas2 & "','" & _
                                    AddConjuntoCasas2 & "'," & AddEstratoCasas2 & ",'" & AddMatriculaCasas2 & "','" & _
                                    AddCedulaCatastralCasas2 & "','" & AddEscrituraCasas2 & "','" & AddNotariaCasas2 & "'," & _
                                    AddAnoCasas2 & "," & AddMetros2Casas2 & ",'" & AddTipoConstruccionCasas2 & "'," & _
                                    AddNivelesCasas2 & "," & AddHabitacionesCasas2 & "," & AddGarajesCasas2 & ",'" & _
                                    AddTechoCasas2 & "','" & AddVistaCasas2 & "','" & AddPicinaCasas2 & "','" & AddCocinaIntegralCasas2 & "','" & _
                                    AddBarCasas2 & "','" & AddCuartoCasas2 & "','" & AddAnteJardinCasas2 & "','" & AddEquiposCasas2 & "','" & _
                                    AddAireAcondicionadoCasas2 & "','" & AddDetallesAddicionalesCasas2 & "','" & AddEstiloCasas2 & "'," & _
                                    AddAnoConstruccionCasas2 & ",'" & AddOrientacionCasas2 & "'," & AddBanoCasas2 & "," & _
                                    AddParqueoCasas2 & ",'" & AddPisoCasas2 & "','" & AddBalconCasas2 & "','" & AddJacuzziCasas2 & "','" & _
                                    AddChimeneaCasas2 & "','" & AddTVCasas2 & "','" & AddZonaLavanderiaCasas2 & "','" & AddPatioCasas2 & "','" & _
                                    AddAccesoriosCasas2 & "','" & AddCalefaccionCasas2 & "','" & AddAdministracionCasas2 & "','" & _
                                    AddAmenidadesCasas2 & "','" & AddImpuestosCasas2 & "','" & AddCondicionesCasas2 & "','" & _
                                    AddOcupacionCasas2 & "','" & AddCuotaAdministracionCasas2 & "','" & AddRestriccionesCasas2 & "','" & _
                                    AddSeguridadCasas2 & "','" & AddMonstrarCasas2 & "','" & AddComisionCasas2 & "','" & _
                                    AddFechaListadoCasas2 & "','" & AddAgenteCooperanteCasas2 & "','" & _
                                    AddFecdhaExpiracionCasas2 & "','" & _
                                    AddCiudadEscrituraCasas2 & "','" & AgenteNameCasas2 & "','" & _
                                    AgenteLicensiaCasas2 & "','" & AgenteCompaniaCasas2 & "','" & _
                                    AgentePersonalCasas2 & "','" & AgenteTelefonoCasas2 & "','" & _
                                    AgenteFaxCasas2 & "','" & AgenteEmailCasas2 & "'," & AddAreaLotesM2Casas2 & "," & AddPrecioOriginalCasas2 & ", '" & AgenteAccountCreatorCasas2 & "', 0 );"
```

AddFechaListadoCasas2 and AddFecdhaExpiracionCasas2 are Strings that contains the date i want to input on MySQL

Comment: What datatype do you have for your table column where you're storing the date?

Comment: @Cory on mysql database is date format is as date, on the program im placing it on a string to later save it on mysql but it seem that i have to convert that string into a date then format it and save it. that is the part where i havent been successful.

Comment: Did some mention [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current query is vulnerable with `SQL Injection`. Please make use of `ADONet Object` such as `Connection` and `Command` with parameters. To be more specific, since you are using `MySQL`, use `MySQL Data provider`. It will automatically cast the data types for you.

```
Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO tableName (dateColumn) VALUES (@dateParam)"
Using conn As New MySqlConnection("connectionstringHere")
    Using comm As New MySqlCommand()
        With comm
            .Connection = conn
            .CommandText = query
            .CommandType = Commandtype.Text
            ' Assuming this is a DatePicker '
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateParam", AddCasasListadoDatePicker.Value) 
        End With
        Try
            conn.Open()
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch(ex as MySqlException)
            Msgbox(ex.Message.ToString())
        End Try
    End Using
End Using
```