# Datetimepicker returning a null value in mysql. [VB.NET]

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Here is my code:

```
'" & DateTimePicker1.Value & "')"
```

It keeps returning this in mysql, what am I doing wrong? "0000-00-00"

Also the type of the column in phpmyadmin is DATE

Comment: Are you sure the query statement is executing correctly? Where is that code?

Comment: I hope you have an opening bracket for that string, because there is one after the '.

Comment: What is the column type for dob?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to vb.net date save to mysql date with no 0000-00-00](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684345/how-to-vb-net-date-save-to-mysql-date-with-no-0000-00-00)

Comment: Dont use ticks, Dont concat SQL and dont pass text

Comment: I came across that thread too and I couldn't figure that out. What you mean I am using a vb.net application, I will update the post with the whole code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can specify the format like that. Try this:

```
DateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString("d")
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx

**Update**

MSSQL wants a specific format for dates - YYYYMMDD.

```
DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
```

Comment: Tried this, also returning null value

Comment: [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) types do not have formats and cannot be formatted. They are a value.  Formats are for displaying to humans.

Comment: @Plutonix I don't understand. We are converting the value to a string via ToString, the format of the string will be the one specified by "d".

Answer (score 0):

DateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString()

You also might try putting CAST('" & DateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString() & "' AS date)